# Displaying a Percent on an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Okay, maybe I am looking to hard or been up to long but this is driving me crazy.  I am trying to display the percentage on a View but it always shows as 0.  What simple thing am I doing wrong?

```
    int iNumber;
    float fNumber;

fNumber  = 3/ 24;
iNumber = 3 / 24;
NSLog(@"iNumber: %d", iNumber);
NSLog(@"fNumber: %f", fNumber);

NSNumberFormatter *numFormatterII = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSNumber *scoreII = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: fNumber];
    [numFormatterII setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
    lblOddsToBust.text = [numFormatterII stringFromNumber: scoreII];

Results always:
iNumber: 0
fNumber: 0.000000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dividing integers, which gives an integer as an answer (in this case it is being rounded down to 0).

Try

```
3.0 / 24.0
```

Comment: You guys are awesome...thanks.  Wish I would have asked earler!

Comment: Incidentally, only one of the two numbers needs to be a floating type. 3.0/24 and 3/24.0 should produce the same results.

Answer (score 1):

3/24 which is close to 0. You are seeing an implict conversion of float to int. 
Try 3.0/24.0